# How to Convert a CAGradientLayer to a UIColor with Swift 3 or Hue?

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swift3, cagradientlayer

I was trying to make a background color a gradient with Hue, (https://github.com/hyperoslo/Hue) and I got an error saying backgroundColor only works with UIColor. But would it be possible to change a CAGradientLayer to a UIColor. (I would prefer in the Hue framework, but it in apple frameworks is fine too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example right on the hue page you linked to:

```
    lazy var gradient: CAGradientLayer = [
      UIColor(hex: "#FD4340"),
      UIColor(hex: "#CE2BAE")
      ].gradient { gradient in
        gradient.speed = 0
        gradient.timeOffset = 0

        return gradient
      }
```

All you need to do is add it to your view as a sublayer.

```
    view.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

Comment: Would it be possible to turn this into a UIColor? Or have it target a specific element?

Comment: A UIColor cannot be a gradient; it is always a single color except in the bizarre case of UIColor(patternImage image: UIImage).  I guess you can render your gradient to an image and use it as a pattern image color.  Its much easier to just add the CAGradientLayer to an existing view.